# How to include a file (class) in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

i wanna import and view excel file using php, so i have a found a library class  [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

when we use php, we just include the file in the page using `include("nameoffile.php");`

i don't know how to do that using symfony.
where should i import ? and how?`

Comment: Symfony actually *is* PHP, so the exact same thing technically works as well so I wonder a bit what you want to know about specifically.

Comment: you can add this Bundle: https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

Comment: thank you, i added the bundle, and it work great! thank's for ur answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for PHPExcel as opposed to the reader but the principle is the same.  No need to actually include files.  They can be autoloaded.

Add to your autoload.php:

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Twig_Extensions_' => $ws.'Symfony/vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
    'Twig_'            => $ws.'Symfony/vendor/twig/lib',
    'Zend_'            => $ws.'ZendFramework-1.11.11/library',
    'PHPExcel'         => $ws.'PHPExcel/Classes' // Change to support the reader
));
```

After which you can do something like:

```
$reader = new \Spreadsheet_Reader();
```

Note the leading slash is required to handle the non-namespaced library.

I abstracted things just a bit by using a service:

```
/* ==================================================
 * Wrap interface to the excel spreasheet processing
 */
namespace Zayso\CoreBundle\Component\Format;

class Excel
{
    public function newSpreadSheet()
    {
        return new \PHPExcel();
    }
    public function newWriter($ss)
    {
        return \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($ss, 'Excel5');
    }
    public function load($file)
    {
        return \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which require a file.
You have [an example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#requiring-files) in the official documentation.

Comment: At the moment there is no such example in documentation :(

Comment: My bad. Seems that the example have been moved [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#requiring-files).